# Error: passing 'const T' as 'this' argument of 'bool T::operator<(T)' discards qualifiers

Tags: c++, class, sorting, vector

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
class MyData
    {
    public:
        int m_iData;
        bool operator<(MyData rhs) { return m_iData < rhs.m_iData; }
    };

int main () 
{
    std:: vector <MyData> myvector(2, MyData() );
    myvector[0].m_iData=2; myvector[1].m_iData=4;

    std::sort(myvector.begin(), myvector.end()); 
}
```

Attempting to compile this gives:

```
error: passing 'const MyData' as 'this' argument of 'bool MyData::operator<(MyData)'
discards qualifiers
```

Comment: Please change the `--` in the title to `T`. I had a hard time to understand the question. (I don't know why I don't have an edit button on this question, though ...)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The comparison operator will be called on a const-reference of a class instance, so it must be declared as a const member function.

It is also good practice to pass the argument by const-reference rather than by value, although it doesn't make much of a difference for your simple class:

```
bool operator<(const MyData & rhs) const { return m_iData < rhs.m_iData; }
//             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^      ^^^^^
//             if you like         mandatory
```

It is generally highly recommended to declare *all* member functions constant which do not mutate your object. This does not only communicate your intention and design, but it would also not be possible otherwise to use those functions on constant objects or references.

Answer (score 5):

An `operator<` should be `const` for both arguments:

```
    bool operator<(MyData const& rhs) const { return m_iData < rhs.m_iData; }
```

Comment: It worked, thanks. Good hint on the referencing too. I hadn't thought of that.

Answer (score 0):

You should write an operator with `const` operands. Have a look [here](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/cpp/threads/287763/1238320#post1238320).